# Vote freeze bug

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface, ajax

Typically, the votes displayed alongside a question or answer highlight if one of those votes was yours.  However, it can sometimes take a very long time for that coloring to come in (sometimes > 10 seconds for me, on several different networks and using several different computers).  I am not sure why this lagtime is so large, but it causes the following problem:

Upon loading the page, when encountering an answer that you already read and definitely meant to vote on, it is natural to click the vote button.  However, when you do this, if it turns out that you really *had* voted (with no indication that this had been the case) you get the following behavior:

1. You get an error stating that your vote is now frozen until there is an edit.
2. The vote that you previously had *is not removed* (meaning that there was no actual vote or unvote that took place to cause the freeze, which means that this does not exhibit the same behavior as actual un-upvote or un-downvote)

This has happened to me a number of times already. Is there anything that can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually just a minor bug.  This happens when you have voted on the question already.

The vote that you previously had is not removed (meaning that there was no actual vote or unvote that took place to cause the freeze, which means that this does not exhibit the same behavior as actual un-upvote or un-downvote)

You cannot un-upvote unless edits are made.